# What validations does devise provide out of the box? (and where are they located)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-6

I think devise provides a `uniqueness: true` validation on User `email` (although I'm not sure where).

I spot this (approximate) email validation regex in `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
  # Email regex used to validate email formats. It simply asserts that
  # one (and only one) @ exists in the given string. This is mainly
  # to give user feedback and not to assert the e-mail validity.
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
```

As well as a validation on password length in the same file:

```
  # ==> Configuration for :validatable
  # Range for password length.
  config.password_length = 6..128
```

#### Question

Does devise provide any other validations out of the box, and if so, where can I find them?

NB the only reason for wanting to know is so I can write any additional validations in `models/user.rb` and I want to keep the code DRY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unique validations for `email` are on the database level https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/81bf3ad8c1e3812448ba4588598493c8e80ecf10/lib/generators/active_record/templates/migration.rb#L15

After running the devise generator and migrations you should see in your `schema.rb`:

```rb
t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
```

The initial devise generator will provide these unique indices out of the box:

```rb
    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
```

Other Devise Validations are listed here https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/81bf3ad8c1e3812448ba4588598493c8e80ecf10/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L19-L44